# Pandas DatetimeIndex vs to_datetime discrepancies

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I'm trying to convert a Pandas Series of epoch timestamps to human-readable times.  There are at least two obvious ways to do this: `pd.DatetimeIndex` and `pd.to_datetime()`.  They seem to work in quite different ways:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [3]: nanos = pd.Series([1462282258000000000, 1462282258100000000, 1462282258200000000])

In [4]: pd.to_datetime(nanos)
Out[4]: 
0   2016-05-03 13:30:58.000
1   2016-05-03 13:30:58.100
2   2016-05-03 13:30:58.200
dtype: datetime64[ns]

In [5]: pd.DatetimeIndex(nanos)
Out[5]: 
DatetimeIndex([       '2016-05-03 13:30:58', '2016-05-03 13:30:58.100000',
               '2016-05-03 13:30:58.200000'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

With `to_datetime()`, the display resolution is milliseconds, and `.000` is printed on whole seconds.  With `DatetimeIndex`, the display resolution is microseconds (which I like), but the decimal part is completely omitted on whole seconds.

Then, try converting the time zone:

```
In [12]: pd.DatetimeIndex(nanos).tz_localize('UTC')                   
Out[12]: 
DatetimeIndex([       '2016-05-03 13:30:58+00:00',
               '2016-05-03 13:30:58.100000+00:00',
               '2016-05-03 13:30:58.200000+00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns, UTC]', freq=None)

In [13]: pd.to_datetime(nanos).tz_localize('UTC')  
TypeError: index is not a valid DatetimeIndex or PeriodIndex
```

This is strange: the timezone functions don't work with a plain datetime Series, only with a DatetimeIndex.  Why would that be?  The `tz_localize()` method exists and is documented here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.tz_localize.html

I've tried Pandas 0.17.0 and 0.18.1 with the same results.

I'm not trying to make an actual index, so all else being equal I would have expected to use `to_datetime()` - I just can't get time zone methods to work with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is 1 way to convert things, `pd.to_datetime()`, yes you can directly construct a `DatetimeIndex`, but it is restrictive on purpose, while `to_datetime` is quite flexible.

So `to_datetime` will give you a similar object to what you input, if you input an array-like, then you will get a `DatetimeIndex`, input a `Series` you will get a `Series`.

```
In [5]: nanos = [1462282258000000000, 1462282258100000000, 1462282258200000000]
```

By default it will convert with a `unit='ns'` which lines up here

```
In [7]: pd.to_datetime(nanos)
Out[7]: DatetimeIndex(['2016-05-03 13:30:58', '2016-05-03 13:30:58.100000', '2016-05-03 13:30:58.200000'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

So one thing we could do is make a Series out of this. The *index* is INTEGER here, the *values* are Datetimes.

```
In [10]: s = Series(pd.to_datetime(nanos))

In [11]: s
Out[11]: 
0   2016-05-03 13:30:58.000
1   2016-05-03 13:30:58.100
2   2016-05-03 13:30:58.200
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

You then can use the `.dt` accessor to operate on the *values*. `Series.tz_localize` operates on the *index*.

```
In [12]: s.dt.tz_localize('US/Eastern')
Out[12]: 
0          2016-05-03 13:30:58-04:00
1   2016-05-03 13:30:58.100000-04:00
2   2016-05-03 13:30:58.200000-04:00
dtype: datetime64[ns, US/Eastern]
```

Comment: OK, so this works: `pd.to_datetime(nanos).dt.tz_localize('UTC').dt.tz_convert('US/Eastern')` - but the docs for `Series.tz_localize()` don't seem to mention `dt` at all, so that's pretty non-discoverable.  Thanks for the expert help.  Do you have any idea how I can make Pandas always print the microseconds part even when it's zero?

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#time-date-components tons of docs

Comment: I was hoping for something similar to `pd.options.display.max_rows` which controls how things are printed without having to reimplement the printing code.  No such luck I guess.

Comment: that is implemented for Series displays but not for Insex as that is amazingly complex - if u want to contribute a patch great